# R change an element in a character string to the most recent element of a different type

Tags: r

Suppose I have a vector such as

```
vec <- c('blue', 'XX', 'XX', 'XX', 'green', 'XXX', 'XXX', 'purple', 'XX', 'XXX')
```

I want to change all the elements that contain an X to whatever the last color element was.

So the desired output would be

```
 "blue"   "blue"   "blue"   "blue"   "green"  "green"  "green"  "purple" "purple" "purple"
```

I expect there's something in the stringr package that could be used (possibly with an ifelse statement?) but I don't know what it is. 
Thanks!
(edited for formatting)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
library(zoo)

vec <- c('blue', 'XX', 'XX', 'XX', 'green', 'XXX', 'XXX', 'purple', 'XX', 'XXX')
vec[grepl('x', vec, ignore.case = TRUE)] <- NA
na.locf(vec)
```

Comment: or if you want it non-destructively: `na.locf(replace(vec, grepl("X", vec), NA))`